# to extract dynamic value from label using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

How can I read the temporary password whose value changes every time user login using `selenium webdriver`.

Below is the tag:

```
<label id="-label" class="ng-binding" for="field-4ace98d61e594685a556941b8d8a92fb-Success">
```

Comment: Which password you are talking about ? are you want to access this `for="field-4ace98d61e594685a556941b8d8a92fb-Success"`?

Comment: nope. I know how to access this field . for field-4ace98d61e594685a556941b8d8a92fb-Success this one password get generated in a label which has id : field-d10f2f19ad874c1ca835ba0f9a5d0cf7-Success. and it get changed evrytime you login . I want to extract the string gernerated like "The temporary password id is awsdDGSG!".

Comment: So can you post the some more here and attach the snap how it look like

Comment: its tage is like this :  <input id="field-d10f2f19ad874c1ca835ba0f9a5d0cf7-Success" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" type="text" aria-describedby="field-d10f2f19ad874c1ca835ba0f9a5d0cf7-Success-help" aria-labelledby="field-d10f2f19ad874c1ca835ba0f9a5d0cf7-Success-label" ng-required="spFormItem.required" ng-disabled="spFormItem.disabled" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" tabindex="50" ng-model="ngModel" aria-disabled="true" disabled="disabled" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false"/>

Comment: Still not clear. Is the password contained in a `<label>` (your question) or `<input>´ (your comment). Please edit your question and paste the element which actually contains the data you want to extract.

Comment: the parent tag is label : <label id="-label" class="ng-binding" for="field-7d4c5d8b73ca4d858316b67321d304ca-Success">
<!-- ngIf: spFormItem.required -->
<!-- ngIf: spFormItem.required -->
</label>
<input id..

Comment: the complete xpath is : html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/section[2]/div/div/sp-work-item/div/div/sp-work-item-form/sp-form/div/div[2]/div/sp-form-item[2]/div[2]/sp-form-item/div/div/input

Comment: share html code for the string The temporary password id is awsdDGSG!